# What does "give lower grade offered to somebody" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean and is it a good or bad thing for working-class students?

"Last month, Labour politician David Lammy called for Oxbridge to give lower grade offered to working-class students."

Source:http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/11/09/big-issue-seller-wins-dream-place-Cambridge-university/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a typo (it is certainly ungrammatical). I think that it should read:

> Last month, Labour politician David Lammy called for Oxbridge to give **lower-grade offers** to working-class students.

In other words, Oxford and Cambridge should make it academically easier for working-class students to gain entry to their courses.